# CSS - Cómo hacer responsive un google bar-chart dentro de un div?

Tags: javascript, css

Estoy implementando el bar-chart del siguiente demo:
https://codepen.io/flopreynat/pen/BfLkA

El mismo consiste en un div que contiene el gráfico de barras ('chart_div1') y su padre cuyo div contiene la clase 'ROW'.

Sin embargo, si quiero colocar todo ello dentro de un div cuyo estilo es `max-widht:900px` y `margin-left:auto` y `margin-right:auto` para centrarlo, el responsive no funciona correctamente. (No toma el tamaño total dentro de los 900 pixeles y se compacta)

Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve viendo un poco el codigo y esto es debido a que este codigo trae unos estilos ya predefinidos para el responsive, los cuales se encuentran en el js:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  drawChart1();
  drawChart2();
});
```

Quitando esta funcion de javascript ya podrias definir tu propio codigo css sin solaparlo con el tuyo, el unico problema seria que perderias el responsive y tendrias que programarlo todo por tu cuenta, respecto al css, lo que quieres hacer lo peudes hacer desde el div row de la siguiente manera

```
.row {
max-width: 950px;
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Esta es la forma de que tu codigo css funcione, sin embargo, como te dije, le quitarias la opcion responsive inicial que tiene el proyecto

Comment: Gracias, era al revés. no había copiado la función del resize. Gracias!!